# how to use gpg encrypted oauth files via Python for offlineimap

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, gnupg

I was playing around with oauth2 to get a better understanding of it. For this reason, I've installed offlineimap which should act as a third-party app. I've found a nice way to read encrypted credentials here on [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44214/encrypt-offlineimap-password/48355#48355).

Based on the linked post I've modified/copied the following python script:

```
import subprocess
import os
import json

def passwd(file_name):
  acct = os.path.basename(file_name)
  path = "/PATHTOFILE/%s" % file_name
  args = ["gpg", "--use-agent", "--quiet", "--batch", "-d", path]
  try:
    return subprocess.check_output(args).strip()
  except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    return ""

def oauthpasswd(acct, key):
  acct = os.path.basename(acct)
  path = "/PATHTOFILE/%s_oauth2.gpg" % acct
  args = ["gpg", "--use-agent", "--quiet", "--batch", "-d", path]
  try:
    return str(json.loads(subprocess.check_output(args).strip())['installed'][key])
  except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    return ""

def prime_gpg_agent():
  ret = False
  i = 1
  while not ret:
    ret = (passwd("prime.gpg") == "prime")
    if i > 2:
      from offlineimap.ui import getglobalui
      sys.stderr.write("Error reading in passwords. Terminating.\n")
      getglobalui().terminate()
    i += 1
  return ret

prime_gpg_agent()
```

In the corresponding offlineimaprc file I call the function with the correct arguments:

```
oauth2_client_id = oauthpasswd('gmail', 'client_id')
oauth2_client_secret = oauthpasswd('gmail', 'client_secret')
oauth2_request_url = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
oauth2_refresh_token = passwd('gmail_rf_token.gpg')
```

Please note in the local file the `PATHTOFILE` is set correctly. What I've done was downloaded the JSON file from Google including the oauth2 credentials and encrypted it. I've stored the refresh token in a separate file. 
However, if I run offlineimap I get an authentication error:

```
 ERROR: While attempting to sync account 'gmail'
  ('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x7f488c214320>) (configuration is: {'client_secret': "oauthpasswd('gmail', 'client_secret')", 'grant_type': 'refresh_token', 'refresh_token': "passwd('gmail_rf_token.gpg')", 'client_id': "oauthpasswd('gmail', 'client_id')"})
```

I've tried then to check the outputs of the two python functions `passwd` and `oauthpasswd` in a python interpreter. I get the desired outputs. Even more, I've copied the output from the functions within the python interpreter to the offlineimaprc config file and I was able to sync to Gmail. This implies that there must be a mistake when offlineimap executes the file but I can't see what's wrong.

If I only encrypt my Gmail password everything is working. This means there is something going wrong from the details downloaded from Google (client_id, client_secret and refresh token). As pointed out above, the values itself are correct. I've really copied the output of

```
oauthpasswd('gmail', 'client_id')
oauthpasswd('gmail', 'client_secret')
passwd('gmail_rf_token.gpg')
```

from a python console to the offlineimaprc file and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem which happens is the following. According to this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395576/can-we-encrypt-any-field-in-offlineimaprc) offlineimap does not allow for encryption of all keys within the offlinemaprc file. That's why the python function never gets evaluated and the wrong strings are handed over.